# flowtype: package.json not found in PackageHeap

Tags: javascript, npm, flowtype

I decided to try and run [Flow](http://flowtype.org) on some existing javascript code. There's only one external library, [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/index.html), and flow is throwing the following error:

```
(12111) infer_job THROWS: Failure("internal error: package ~/Code/chess/node_modules/ramda/package.json not found in PackageHeap")
```

A quick google search only turned up the actual Flow source code.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! And it appeared only today, after months of using flow without problems. I have made a bug report to Flow - https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1178 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all the packages to the `[include]` part of `.flowconfig`. Like this:

```
[include]
../node_modules/ramda
```

It should start working then.